# How to parse data from Controller to view using JQGrid?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I am trying to pass data from controller to GQ grid. I have done implemented the SQL operation - selecting a row- in another file and returning a object of list type `List<Models.ViewModel.Itegration>`  to the Controller. I implemented the controller of type `JsonResult` which returns the data in json format. The controller is using `[HttpGet]` Attritute. I have attached code of my controller, html, js file and screenshot of the issue. The ***Google Console*** is not showing any problem. The table is getting ready, but the table data is showing. I guess there is the issue with "passing the data" properly. It would be very helpful for me if anybody could just check my code and let me know where I am getting wrong.

Additionally, is there any software, where I can check where the issue is coming while connecting to server, because in this case Google inspect tool is not helpful at  all.

In my controller, by using breakpoint I have checked that in  `Integrations value = db.GetIntegrationRow();` I am getting a correct value in `value`.
Controller:

```
#region Namespace

using MCNIDev.DBAccess;
using MCNIDev.Models.ViewModel;
using MCNIDev.Processor.Services;

using System.Web.Mvc;

#endregion

namespace MCNIDev.Content
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This controller class is responsible for all action in  Integration view
    /// </summary>
    public class IntegrationsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Details()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To get the data for JQGrid
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Detail()
        {

            IntegrationsProcessor db = new IntegrationsProcessor(new MCNIDbContext());
            Integrations value = db.GetIntegrationRow();

            return new JsonResult()
            {
                               Data = value,
                               JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
           
        }

    }
}
```

HTML file

```
@using MCNIDev.CustomControls
@model MCNIDev.Models.ViewModel.Integrations


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devicexb c-width" />
    <title>Integrations</title>
</head>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/toasterCss")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/dataPickerCss")
<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        min-width: 80px !important;
    }
</style>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "Integrations", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", id = "frmManifestOrders" }))
    {
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Integrations</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div><!-- /.content-header -->

        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="card card-block">
                    <div class="row table-responsive">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <table id="tblSelectIntegrations"></table>
                                    <div id="divSelect"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <hr />
                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="document.location.href='/Dashboard/Dashboard';" value="Cancel" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    }
</body>
</html>
@*Bundle file includes the path to single JavaScript file Integration that does GQGrid operation *@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/integrations")
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    Integrate.GetValue();
});
</script>
```

JavaScript file:

```
var Integrate = function() {
function GetValue() {
    $("#tblSelectIntegrations").jqGrid({
        mtype: "GET",
        url: "/Integrations/Detail",
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        colNames: [
            "First Name", "Email Address",""
        ],
        colModel: [
            //{
            //    name: '',
            //    key: false,
            //    width: 30,
            //    editable: true,
            //    formatter: function () {
            //        return "<input type='checkbox' value='Select' class='fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left noPrint'\>";
            //    }
            //},
            { key: false, name: 'IntegrationName', index: 'IntegrationName', editable: false, width: 200 },
            { key: false, name: 'CompanyEmail', index: 'CompanyEmail', editable: false, width: 200 },
         { key: false, name: 'Blank', index: 'Blank', editable: false, width: 200 }
        ],
        pager: jQuery("#divSelect"),
        rowNum: 1,
        scroll: 0,
        height: $(window).innerHeight() - 450,
        width: "100%",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Product",
        emptyrecords: "No records to display",
        jsonReader: {
            root: "",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false,
        loadonce: false,
        ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
              
    }).navGrid("tblSelectIntegrations", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
}
return {
        GetValue: GetValue
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in **controller**. I am trying to send data without telling JQGrid where to insert data.

```
var jsonData = new
            {
                rows = value
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Replace below code with above code

```
return new JsonResult()
            {
                               Data = value,
                               JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
```

In my first code I've mentioned that add my data in the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
return new JsonResult()
            {
                               Data = value,
                               JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
```

Replace the above code with the below code.

```
int totalRecords = value.Count();
   var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
    var JsonData = new
                        {
                            total = totalPages,
                            page,
                            records = totalRecords,
                            rows = value 
                        };
                        return Json(JsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```